# Appending to Nested Dictionary with Identical Keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list containing values that should be used as keys for a dictionary. Right now the list to be converted to keys looks like the following:

```
myList = ["A", "B"]
```

I am converting this list to be the keys to a dictionary by doing the following:

```
newDict = dict.fromkeys(myList, {"Min":[], "Max":[], "Avg":[]})
```

When printing newDict I get the output:

```
{'A': {'Min': [], 'Max': [], 'Avg': []}, 'B': {'Min': [], 'Max': [], 'Avg': []}}
```

However, when trying to write to the `newDict["B"]["Avg"]` list, the value gets added to both the `"A"` and `"B"` keys:

Code:

```
newDict["B"]["Avg"].append(111)
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'Min': [], 'Max': [], 'Avg': [111]}, 'B': {'Min': [], 'Max': [], 'Avg': [111]}}
```

Is there for the appended value to only be added to the intended key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Comment: Both `A` and `B` keys refer to the _same object!_

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked Python questions. You have multiple references to the same object. See the duplicate answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This comes a lot when handling arrays and dicts.
What I prefer to do is use list/dict comprehensions to initialize a new object every time.

```py
newDict = {k: {"Min":[], "Max":[], "Avg":[]} for k in myList}
```

With the initial method, your keys are pointing at the same object with the same id. You may briefly check this with a simple

```py
newDict['A'] is newDict['B'] # True
```

class names can be camelCase, but not variables. Maybe pep8 will help you further in your journey through python. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's because both the keys are given the value `{"Min":[], "Max":[], "Avg":[]}`, which is the one dict in both case, rather than two identical dicts.

You can verify by calling `id` on each dict.

```py
[id(v) for v in newDict.values()] # gives [4618156608, 4618156608]
```

Or as @FlorianAendekerk suggested, with `is`

```py
newDict["A"] is newDict["B"]  # gives True
```

You can fix it by creating a new dictionnary for each key for instance with a dict comprehenssion:

```py
newDict = {k: {"Min":[], "Max":[], "Avg":[]} for k in myList}
```

PS. you should check out [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) as variables are not suposed to be camelCase or PascalCase.

Comment: calling `newDict["A"] is newDict["B"]` will also indicate both refer to the same object